# How to remove the multi level indexing from axis=0

Tags: python, aggregation

I have applied df.groupby().agg() method on an initial dataframe and got the bellow dataframe. How can I remove the second row containing "median, median,q1,q2,median,median,median,median'?

```
        X              Y      Z     W            A     B       C     D
      median         median   q1   q2          median median median median 
0   0.765699            0.0  0.0  0.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
1   0.852869            0.0  0.0  0.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
2   0.751222            0.0  0.0  2.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
3   0.899825            0.0  2.0  2.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
4   0.876273            0.0  0.0  0.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
..       ...            ...  ...  ...             ...    ...    ...    ...   
95  0.960199            0.0  0.0  0.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
96  0.940533            0.0  0.0  0.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
97  0.843790            0.0  1.0  1.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
98  0.969018            0.0  0.0  0.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
99  0.956095            0.0  1.0  1.0             0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: try `df.groupby().agg().reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the second row of dataframe, you can use `df.drop(1)`.

```
df = df.drop(1)
```